# Draggable dialog as draggable iframe(or draggable div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a parent page and a dialog in my page.

My problem is:

- when my dialog opened, it has width and height same parent page width and height.
- I use draggable property for dialog, and i can move it in parent page.
- When i chose a item in dialog then information of item append to parent page, i want to see information in parent page, but dialog has lag width and i can't see anything in parent page.
- I want my dialog draggable as example: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
  (I want to hide part of dialog as example)

Update info:

link 1:http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Link2:http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

(Dialog in link2 as my dialog)

You can see:

- Example in link1: You can move and hide a part of element( see attach: img1)
- Example in link2:  You can move dialog but it can't hide behind the parent element(see attach: img1)

I want dialog in link 2 can move as link1.

Attach:
Img1:

[image]

Img2:

[image]

Is there any solution for me?
(I'm trying to learning E, if you don't understand, please tell me.:()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include your code with the question to get better help since I don't actually understand the problem...?

for first problem you should set width and height of your dialog element

```
#draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

like this and you should have kind of box like example you wanted..

your **link 1** and **link 2** is actually same link..

I  think you are looking for **overflow:hidden**

which will look something like this in your css:

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

and this will hide anything goes over your window and not expand your window.

check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks you, i've just update some info in my question.:)

Comment: ohh, i'm sorry.Link2 is: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/    . I want dialog in link 2 can move and hide as link 1. I try to user overflow: hidden in body but it not ok.

Comment: Use can check it in link: http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/ . I'm trying to use overflow, but it not ok. hjc